# Json object to arrays for network graph

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, highcharts-ng

I am trying to build a network graph which has the points data as [[from, to], [from,to]]. So, I need to build an array of this form from a JSON object. Can you give me a way that I can do it? I know, its just the way how we apply logic, but I tried lot many ways and I couldn't able to do it. Hence I am here to get a nice logic which applies for any depth of object.

My sample object is like

```
myObj = {
  Continents : 
  { Asia : {
      India : 1,
      China: 2 ,
      Japan : 3
    },
    Europe : {
      Sweden: 1,
      Norway : 2,
      Finland : 4,
      Denmark : 5
    },
    Africa : {
      Congo : 1,
      Kenya: 2,
      Zimbabwe : 3
    }
  }
}
```

Depth of the object can vary. And now I have to make an array to form nodes as below.

```
myArray = [['Continents', 'Asia'],
           ['Continents', 'Europe'],
           ['Continents'], 'Africa'],
           ['Asia','India'],
           ['Asia','China'],
           ['Asia','Japan'],
           ['Europe', 'Sweden'],
           ['Europe', 'Norway'],
           ['Europe', 'Finland'],
           ['Europe', 'Denmark'],
           ['Africa', 'Congo'],
           ['Africa', 'Kenya'],
           ['Africa', 'Zimbabwe'],
]
```

Comment: `Depth of the object can vary.`  You need to explain the potential variations.  We can only help with what you give us, which is currently a clearly defined structure.

Comment: @Archer If I get the solution for the posted object, I think I can make a solution out of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a recursive generator:

```
  function* pairs(obj, parent) {
    for(const [key, value] of Object.entries(obj)) {
       if(parent) yield [parent, key];
       if(typeof value === "object")
          yield* pairs(value, key);
    }
 }
```

Usable as:

```
  const result = [...pairs(obj)];
```

Comment: Good solution. But seems it is works only in node.js and ES6. Its not working on Angular/Typescript